# Custom Fields help

Tags: post-meta, advanced-custom-fields

After read a lot in a lot of sites, finally I was able to do something similar what I was trying (read a lot because I don't know code at all), is the follow:

I want to use a background image for my custom fields.

I did this in `single.php`:

```
<div class="post-meta">
         <h3>
             <?php $firstCF = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'firstCF', true);
if ($dorigen) { ?>
             My text: <?php echo $firstCF; ?></br></br>
  <?php } 
else { ?>  </h3><?php } ?>
<h3>
             <?php $secondCF = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'secondCF', true);
if ($dorigen) { ?>
             Other Text: <?php echo $secondCF; ?></br></br>
  <?php } 
else { ?> </h3><?php } ?>
         </div>`

CSS: 
.post-meta {
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #252525;
    color: #f2f6d7;
    padding-top: 22px;
    padding-left: 190px;
    float: left;
    height: 150px;
    width: 600px;
    background-image: url(../images/fondo-campos-personalizados.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
}
```

The problem is that will not use always `firstCF` and/or `secondCF` in all my post and the background image always is there.

Another Q: I use `h3`, but when I see source in browser I can't find `</h3>`, but the size and characteristics of the text are really those of my css `h3`. I don't know if Google and others, will understand that they are really `h3`.

Is there a way to do something like this?

Comment: I use that code becouse I use Disqus and Post Rating plugins and those use Custom Fields too. If I use for example: if( the_meta() ) : 
   <div class="cfield">
      <?php the_meta();
sigle.php show info about those plugins..

Comment: I couldn't find a better title for this Question, as it is ***really not clear*** what the Custom Field has to do with the `background-image`... Also, you tagged the Q with Advanced Custom Fields, what does it has to do with this? :::: Please, add more details to the Q itself, you are free to [edit] it whenever needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what $dorigen is - but you can't find your `</h3>` because of your if/else condition. I don't see why the else is needed at all. Replace

```
else { ?> </h3><?php } ?>
```

with

```
</h3>
```

in both places it is used.

That said, if you only want to show the entire post-meta div when the meta values are set, then you should do something like this (untested):

```
<?php
$firstCF = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'firstCF', true );
$secondCF = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'secondCF', true );
if ( $firstCF || $secondCF ) {
    ?>
    <div class="post-meta">
        <h3>
    <?php if ( $dorigen ) { ?>
                My text: <?php echo $firstCF; ?></br></br>
    <?php } ?>  </h3>
        <h3>
    <?php if ( $dorigen ) { ?>
                Other Text: <?php echo $secondCF; ?></br></br>
    <?php } ?> </h3>
</div>
```

I left the dorigen stuff in even though I don't know what it's for.